# Stuck to determine the checkbox is checked to test in selenium webdriver & python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

I want to determine if checkbox is checked or not of my web page under test. I'm using Selenium&Python.

Web page Html snippet:

```
<input class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" _ngcontent-ddp-11="" name="printInput" type="checkbox"/>
```

When i tried

```
chkbox_status = eachDiv.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid']").get_attribute("checked")
```

it always return `True`.

Can someone here help to determine the the checkbox status ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `is_selected()` method:

```
eachDiv.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid']").is_selected()
```

This will return `boolean` `True` if checkbox is checked or `False` otherwise

Also note that you're trying to apply `get_attribute()` to `list`- it cannot return you `True`, but `AttributeError` instead

Comment: Your are right @andersson i made a typo i corrected the html its find_element_by_xpath. Well I tried the .is_selected() as well, it return bool True in this case, irrespective of selection. :|

Comment: Is there only one checkbox on the page? Can you share more details? page `URL`?